# why is my function if/else if/ else if statement returning the same answer?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have a rock, paper, scissors game set up with the user clicking on the buttons labeled "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" which results in the userChoice.
When I run the program the compareChoices() function always returns "The result is a tie, let's play again!", I don't understand why.

```js
  < article >
    < button onclick = "rockPaperScissors('Rock')" > Rock < /button>
    <button onclick="rockPaperScissors('Paper')">Paper</button >
    < button onclick = "rockPaperScissors('Scissors')" > Scissors < /button>
  </article >

    < script type = "text/javascript" >
    function rockPaperScissors(userchoice) {
      alert("You chose " + userchoice + " ...the computer chose " + getComputerChoice() + ".");
      compareChoices();
    }

  function getComputerChoice() {
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
      computerChoice = "Rock";
    } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
      computerChoice = "Paper";
    } else {
      computerChoice = "Scissors";
    }
    return computerChoice;
  }

  function compareChoices(userChoice, ComputerChoice) {
    if (userChoice === ComputerChoice) {
      alert("The result is a tie, let's play again!");
    } else if (userChoice === "Rock") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Scissors") {
        alert("Congratulations, you win!");
      } else {
        alert("The computer wins! Care to play again?");
      }
    } else if (userChoice === "Scissors") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Rock") {
        alert("The computer wins, let's play again!");
      } else {
        alert("Yippie! You win!");
      }
    } else if (userChoice === "Paper") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Rock") {
        alert("The computer wins. Don't give up, try again!");
      } else {
        alert("Hail the all mighty visitor. Give it another go!");
      }
    }
  } < /script>
```

Comment: You are not passing any `arguments` for `compareChoices`

Comment: looks like you're not passing the parameters into the compareChoices() function

Comment: This will help: `var computed = getComputerChoice();
alert("You chose " + userchoice + " ...the computer chose " + computed + ".");
compareChoices(userchoice, computed);`

Comment: If i may remind you, don't forget that in JS all parameters are optional so be carefull when you calling function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing anything into compareChoices

```js
  < article >
    < button onclick = "rockPaperScissors('Rock')" > Rock < /button>
    <button onclick="rockPaperScissors('Paper')">Paper</button >
    < button onclick = "rockPaperScissors('Scissors')" > Scissors < /button>
  </article >

    < script type = "text/javascript" >
    function rockPaperScissors(userchoice) {
      var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
      alert("You chose " + userchoice + " ...the computer chose " + computerChoice + ".");
      compareChoices(userChoice, computerChoice);
    }

  function getComputerChoice() {
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
      computerChoice = "Rock";
    } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
      computerChoice = "Paper";
    } else {
      computerChoice = "Scissors";
    }
    return computerChoice;
  }

  function compareChoices(userChoice, ComputerChoice) {
    if (userChoice === ComputerChoice) {
      alert("The result is a tie, let's play again!");
    } else if (userChoice === "Rock") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Scissors") {
        alert("Congratulations, you win!");
      } else {
        alert("The computer wins! Care to play again?");
      }
    } else if (userChoice === "Scissors") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Rock") {
        alert("The computer wins, let's play again!");
      } else {
        alert("Yippie! You win!");
      }
    } else if (userChoice === "Paper") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Rock") {
        alert("The computer wins. Don't give up, try again!");
      } else {
        alert("Hail the all mighty visitor. Give it another go!");
      }
    }
  } < /script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments to compareChoices().

```
function rockPaperScissors(userchoice) {
      alert("You chose " + userchoice + " ...the computer chose " + getComputerChoice() + ".");
      compareChoices(userchoice, getComputerChoice());
    }
```

You should only alert one time since they are going to come so close together. Something like this:

```
function compareChoices(userChoice, ComputerChoice) {
    var message;
    if (userChoice === ComputerChoice) {
      message = "Computer: " + ComputerChoice + ", User: " + userChoice + " - The result is a tie, let's play again!";
    } else if (userChoice === "Rock") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Scissors") {
        message = "Computer: " + ComputerChoice + ", User: " + userChoice + " - Congratulations, you win!";
      } else {
        message = "Computer: " + ComputerChoice + ", User: " + userChoice + " - The computer wins! Care to play again?");
      }
    } else if (userChoice === "Scissors") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Rock") {
        message = "Computer: " + ComputerChoice + ", User: " + userChoice + " - The computer wins, let's play again!";
      } else {
        message = "Computer: " + ComputerChoice + ", User: " + userChoice + " - Yippie! You win!";
      }
    } else if (userChoice === "Paper") {
      if (ComputerChoice === "Rock") {
        message = "Computer: " + ComputerChoice + ", User: " + userChoice + " - The computer wins. Don't give up, try again!";
      } else {
        message = "Computer: " + ComputerChoice + ", User: " + userChoice + " - Hail the all mighty visitor. Give it another go!";
      }
    }
  alert(message);
}
```

Comment: `getComputerChoice()` will(may) return different values every time it is called.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. You still have to pass the arguments into the function. You need to compare the choices every time someone clicks a button so obviously the getComputerChoice() function will return different values every time it's called. Isn't that the point?

Comment: Check the answer give below...That is the way to go!

Comment: If the function is called every time a button is clicked, that variable will change every single time. They are doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Did you miss `var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. It's setting the exact same result to a variable instead of just passing it to the compareChoices() function. My answer and the answer below are doing the exact same thing.

Comment: I'm not paying attention to the alert. If the alert has to be there, that's the only reason you would need to assign it to a variable.

Comment: **I'm not paying attention to the alert** Why ? OP is providing some info for user there. And that is the only reason. `compareChoices` should calculate things as per the value shown of `getComputerChoice()` in alert!

Comment: Because it would make much more sense to provide that information in the second alert with the result. There are going to be two alerts at the same time which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put the computerchoice into variable, and call comparechoices function with same computerchoice.

```
function rockPaperScissors(userchoice) {
       var computerchoice = getComputerChoice();
       alert("You chose " + userchoice + " ...the computer chose " + computerchoice + ".");
       compareChoices(userchoice, computerchoice);
    }
```